# Will the new Twitter framework work for iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, ios5

Will the new `Twitter API` (framework) included in `iOS 5` work for `iOS 4.3` and above ?

Comment: they don't want me there

Comment: Just a friendly note that http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is for questions of a user nature and any questions on the Developer program, programming, API and code is clearly [off topic](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) there.

Answer (score 5):

It does not work for iOS4.3 as it has been included with iOS5 and later only.

Comment: With hindsight I wish I'd authored a small iOS 4/5 framework that uses the same methods as the Twitter and ACAccount frameworks and released it open source to help people transition to the new way of accessing Twitter on iOS!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will have to use mgtwitterengine with oath. This will be compatible with most iOS versions. Apples api is only for iOS5.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

Comment: Will this work for iOS 4.3 and above. Furthermore this should support ARC as well. So will this help me ?